# exit method from inner lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8

I have method contain lambda expression i want to return from the method by calling return in lambda body but it not work. the return in lambda body don't affect the outer method

```
void X(){
    lmbda -> {
        if (i > j) return;
    }
    some code ....
}
```

Comment: why do you need a lambda here?

Comment: It isn't possible to do this. What is the broader problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: the original code bigger than this example . ineed it in many cases. when iam in lambda body i want to exit from the outer method if condition result true

Answer (score 2):

A *lambda* expression is *independent* of the code invoking it. That is also why everything it uses must be **final** (or at least effectively final).

You could implement such a functionality with the lambda setting a field, for example a `boolean` embed in a final **container class** known at the outer method. The outer method could then detect the `boolean` **change** and `return`. But the *lambda* itself **can not force** the method to `return`.

However it is likely that you should rethink your design, you probably don't need a lambda there.

---

The example I talked about:

```
public class Flag {
    public boolean flag = false;
}

public class YourClass() {
    private final static Flag FLAG = new Flag();

    void X() {
        FLAG.flag = false;

        lmbda -> {
            if (i > j) {
                FLAG.flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (FLAG.flag) {
            FLAG.flag = false;
            return;
        }

        some code ...
    }
}
```

Possible, but definitely not what you would call a *nice design*.